# How to calculate multiplication of two discrete series

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

**Short version**:
How to multiply two discrete sequences?

**Long version**:
Convolution of two discrete sequences is *weighted sum*.

For instance, convolution of two sequences:

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2
```

and:

```
1, 2, 1
```

can be calculated in the following way:

```
1⋅1 + 2⋅2 + 3⋅1 = 1 + 4 + 3 = 8  
2⋅1 + 3⋅2 + 1⋅1 = 2 + 6 + 1 = 9  
3⋅1 + 1⋅2 + 5⋅1 = 3 + 2 + 5 =10  
1⋅1 + 5⋅2 + 1⋅1 = 1 +10 + 1 =12  
5⋅1 + 1⋅2 + 1⋅1 = 5 + 2 + 1 = 8  
1⋅1 + 1⋅2 + 1⋅1 = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4  
1⋅1 + 1⋅2 + 2⋅1 = 1 + 2 + 2 = 5
```

Result is:

```
8, 9,10,12, 8, 4, 5, ?, ?
```

But if both sequences are Fourier images in which way can I calculate their convolution?

Comment: What do you mean by "Fourier images"?

Comment: @MBaz, by "Fourier images" I mean result of discrete Discrete Fourier Transform. Sequence of real numbers can be regarded as one of two quadrature components (I or Q).

Comment: you have to padd your signal in some way so you could obtain the same signal length as your input signal. you could padd signal by zero at the beginning which lead to a causal filter, also you could repeat the first and last element or assume the signal is periodic and when you reach the end of signal the signal will be repeated.

Comment: @MohammadMohammadi,  thanks for notice about padding!

Answer (score 1):

This is like a Hanning window applied in the frequency domain. Assuming you are time windowing in the frequency domain,

If your discrete sequences were in the frequency domain, they would be periodic.

Lets index at the sequence, first line is 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1,1, 2
$$ \begin{array}{c c c c c c c c} 
1& 2 & 3 & 1& 5& 1& 1&1& 2 \\
x[1] & x[2] & x[3] & x[4] & x[5] & x[6] & x[7] & x[8] & x[9]\\ 
x[9]+2x[1]+x[2]& x[1]+2x[2]+x[3]& \dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots& \dots & x[8]+2x[9]+x[1] \\
6   & 7 &9& 10 &12& 8& 4& 5& 6\end{array}
$$
Bottom line is the convolution result 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 8, 4, 5, 6

you could also do this with a conventional convolution, but you need to recognize the shift is a causal effect.  In the frequency domain, $Y[1]$ isn't earlier or later than $Y[2]$. and you have to wrap the results.

Comment: Hi Stanley: I understand some of above but what happened to the x[9]. was that left out purposely ? thanks.

Comment: @Stanley Pawlukiewicz, it looks like my question isn't clear. I'm not interested in convolution, but I try understand how to multiply.

Comment: @mike leeds  thanks for showing the omission

Comment: It's a [Hann window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_von_Hann). Please don't let the "Hanning" spread :)